# how to set TNS_ADMIN path for oracle database connection?

Tags: php, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

I am using ubuntu php7 and apache. when I try to connect db with php script I am receiving fatal error: Fatal error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

php script:

```
<?php
//phpinfo(); exit;

$conn = oci_connect('system', 'oracle', 'oracledb/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
} else echo 'succesful';

exit;
```

phpinfo is showing ocacle lib installed:

[image]
Here is detail about installation oci8 files:

```
unzip /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/ 
unzip /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/ 
unzip /tmp/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip -d /usr/local/

ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_12_2 /usr/local/instantclient 
ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/local/instantclient/libclntsh.so 
ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/instantclient"' >> /root/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a full hostname and domainname where you have 'oracledb'.  Or try an IP address if your DNS server can't resolve the host name.  If you are running PHP on the same machine you have Oracle XE installed on, then use 'localhost', e.g. the connection string would be 'localhost/XE'.  Note you don't need Instant Client if you have PHP installed on the same machine as the database.

For more info, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html